# Python make mutable object behave immutably

Tags: python-3.x

Edit:I am not changing the object's mutability, only making the variable behave like it. I do not have specific implementations in mind, but might use it to make tuples with mutable items hashable

I understand in python you can make immutable objects behave like mutable ones - specifically so that they are not hashable, and that you can edit the object without having to make a new one - by enclosing it in a list, so it behaves like a C pointer:

```
myVar = 5
myVar2 = myVar
#both point to same object 5
myVar += 1
#myVar2 still 5, myVar has new object 6

myVar = [5]
#myVar is no longer immutable
myVar2 = myVar
myVar[0] += 1
#myVar2 is now also 6
```

This means you can change the value of the object a variable points to and it will affect all the variables referencing that object

But is there a way to do it in the opposite - to make mutable objects behave immutably (and  to be hashable)? Tuples will not do - a value inside a tuple can be changed if it is mutable, and a tuple with mutable objects is not hashable. I want to do this mainly so that it can be stored like an immutable object, where variables with the same value all point to the same object, and changes to a variable result in a new object without affecting the other variables, or must I basically re-implememt the python name method with OOP?

Summary: I want an immutable wrapper for a mutable object that, unlike tuples, does not allow the items to be edited, and is hashable

Comment: You understand incorrectly. Immutable objects cannot be *made* mutable. By putting them in a list, you've simply wrapped the immutable object in a mutable container.

Comment: Is this a question?

Comment: What sort of object are you trying to manipulate? i.e., what do you have, and what do you want?

Comment: If I understand this right... You can subclass most types, and make them "behave" immutably, as python is inherently polymorphic.  You just override the setters after init (no idea why you'd want that though). Additionally you can use the "borg design pattern" or class variables to make all references to have the same data (though technically in different objects).  This would get you 90% of the way there I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python has no variables. It has names. All names point to a object.

Attribution makes a name point to a object. It is that simple. You can't make attribution generate a new object implictly.

```
a = x
b = a # means the name "b" also refers to x - regardless if x is mutable or not
```

So no, you can't make mutable objects immutable this way - if someone gets a reference to a mutable object they can mutate it, and all references to that same object will be affected.

Just because an object is immutable doesn't make objects with the same value be the same automatically - try this:

```
>>> x = 'foo bar'
>>> y = ' '.join(['foo', 'bar'])
>>> x == y
True
>>> x is y
False
>>> id(x), id(y)
(139789175899936, 139789175899984)
```

As you can see, they are two different immutable objects, with same value! Both exist separately in memory!

To make them hashable is possible though - you have to define a `__hash__` method that returns some unique hash, that compares equal when the objects are equal - in fact by default all objects already return the id as hash, so you can just wrap in a class:

```
class HashableContainer:
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj

l = [] # mutable, no hash
ic = HashableContainer(l) # mutable, but hashable

d = {}
d[ic] = 'test' # can be used as key
```

However there's a caveat - if you generate a new `HashableContainer` with the same content, it will be considered a different object - because it will have a different hash (based on its id)

Comment: Ideally I'd like different names with the same value of the object it references to point to the same object. Would I have to implement this myself?

Comment: That sentence contradicts itself @nerryoob The "value" of a "name" **is** the object. There are no different values, only different objects. Either it is the same object or it isn't - that is for both mutable or immutable objects. I edited my answer to add example

Comment: @nerryoob your confusion comes from the fact that  `a += 2` won't modify the int object `a` is refering - it creates a new object instead and makes `a` point to it.

Comment: I know how it works - my point is I want a way to make variables referencing mutable objects behave in the same way

Comment: Well, you can make a immutable object - by defining all methods to return a new object instead of mutating it - but you can't change the existing mutable objects to immutable.

Comment: @nerryoob you can also make a immutable wrapper around a mutable object - but if someone has any kind of access to the real underlining mutable object, they will be able to mutate it. Your example `myVar[0] += 1` is mutating the list, not the int - A list is mutable, period.

Comment: Exactly, but I want to know about an immutable wrapper you can use

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174968/discussion-between-nosklo-and-nerryoob).